# Approximation in L1 of step functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume that you have a collection of Borel Measures on $[a,b]$, and you have a function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is integrable with respect to every measure in your collection.

Question 1: I assume it is relatively easy to show that there is a sequence of simple functions that converge in $L^1[a,b]$ of every measure to $f$?

Question 2: Can we do the same with step-functions? I know that if we only had one measure we could do this, but does these funtions depend on the measure? So the same sequence may not work for all the measures? Is it possible to find a sequence that might work for all the measures?

Comment: What is for you the difference between a simple function and a step function?

Comment: @Saz Both can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^Na_iI_{B_i}$, where B_i is a borel set if it is a simple function, and B is a interval if it is a step function.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for Question 1: we can reduce the proof to the case $f \geq 0$. In this  case there exist  non- negative simple functions $f_n$ increasing to $f$ at every point. The fact that $f_n \to f$ in $L^{1}$ w.r.t. any of the measures is an immediate consequence of DCT (or Monotone Convergence Theorem).